# css attr(content) not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Could someone have a look at this example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FnqCp) and tell me how to get content: attr(data-hover) to work in IE10+ it's not working at all except in FireFox. It doesn't even seem to be creating the :before pseudo-element for the anchor . read from line 40 for the a:before class

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li data-content="Home"><a data-hover="Home" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-hover="About" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a data-hover="Services" href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a data-hover="Blogs" href="#">Blogs</a></li>
        <li><a data-hover="Articles" href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a data-hover="Contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>                       
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
header nav ul li a:hover:before {
    color: #355b0f;
    padding: 34px 0; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;        
    text-align: center;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #fff;      
    display: block;

    transition: #6363CE 0.3s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: #6363CE 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Questions on stack overflow should contain reduced code in the question itself (not link to an external resource). Also what have you tried?

Comment: It seems, that something wrong with animation. You can change content value to some fixed value and see, that it still does not work

Comment: I don't know how to do transforms well if any one knows how to fix this to work in IE and Chrome that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

for transition in Chrome and safari u need to add -webkit-transition
also for transform
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp